# Is there a way i could work with this multiindex?

Tags: pandas, multi-index

I have a dataframe like this one, https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Sr29.png. RBD is a code that identifies each school, LET_CUR corresponds to a class and MRUN corresponds to the amount of students in each class, what i need is the following:

I would like to know how many of the schools have at least one class with more than 45 students, so far I haven't figured out yet a code to do that.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Maxi!  Could you please remove the link to the image and provide a code snippet that reproduces the dataframe in its place?  Something like `df = pd.DataFrame(data=[...], index=[...])`.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your `DataFrame` :

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from io import StringIO

>>> df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
RBD,LET_CUR,MRUN
1,A,65
1,B,23
1,C,21
2,A,22
2,B,20
2,C,34
3,A,54
4,A,23
4,B,11
5,A,15
5,C,16
6,A,76"""))
>>> df = df.set_index(['RBD', 'LET_CUR'])
>>> df
            MRUN
RBD LET_CUR     
1   A       65
    B       23
    C       21
2   A       22
    B       20
    C       34
3   A       54
4   A       23
    B       11
5   A       15
    C       16
6   A       76
```

As we want to know the number of school with at leat one class having more than 45 students, we can first filter the `DataFrame` on the column `MRUN` and then use the `nunique()` method to count the number of unique school :

```py
>>> df_filtered = df[df['MRUN'] > 45].reset_index()
>>> df_filtered['RBD'].nunique()
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following (here i build a similar dataframe structure as yours):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'RBD': [1, 1, 2, 3], 
                   'COD_GRADO': ['1', '2', '1', '3'], 
                   'LET_CUR':['A', 'C', 'B', 'A'], 
                   'MRUN':[65, 34, 64, 25]}, 
                   columns=['RBD', 'COD_GRADO', 'LET_CUR', 'MRUN'])
print(df)
n_schools = df.loc[df['MRUN'] >= 45].shape[0]
print(f"Number of shools with 45+ students is {n_schools}")
```

And output, for my example would (table formatted for easier reading):

| (pd indices) | RBD | COD_GRADO | LET_CUR | MRUN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | A | 65 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | C | 34 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | B | 64 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 | A | 25 |

```
> Number of shools with 45+ students is 2
```